# Did Pocahontas quote Greek philosophy?

Tags: soundtrack, pocahontas

In the Disney movie Pocahontas, the titular character sings about the river in *[Just around the River Bend](http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/classicdisney/justaroundtheriverbend.htm)*:

> [Pocahontas] What I love most about rivers is: **You can't step in the
>   same river twice** The water's always changing, always flowing But
>   people, I guess, can't live like that We all must pay a price To be
>   safe, we lose our chance of ever knowing

Was this an intentional quotation from the [works of the Greek philosopher Heraclitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus#Panta_rhei.2C_.22everything_flows.22), or was this merely a coincidence on the part of the Disney songwriters, perhaps sourced from Native American philosophy?

> "Everything changes and nothing remains still ... and ... you cannot
>   step twice into the same stream"

Comment: I feel that that phrase is one of those phrases that get independently thought up alot.

Answer (score 6):

Disney does have a tendency to use philosophical quotes quite often.  My answer would be **yes** (more than likely Heraclitus rather than Native American philosophy) to your question.

This answer is based upon the use of other philosophical quotes in Disney films.

Here are just a few examples, including another from *Pocahontas*:

> The only thing I know is that I know nothing.

Quoted by John Smith in Pocahontas

Quote origin: [Socrates](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Socrates)

> The unexamined life is not worth living.

Quoted by Ursula in The Little Mermaid

Quote origin: [Socrates](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Socrates)

> You can discover more about a person in an hour of play than in a year
>   of conversation.

Quoted by Zazu in the Lion King

Quote origin: [Plato](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Plato)

Comment: +1 for some good examples, but I am preferably looking for canonical sources (eg director interviews).

Comment: @MarchHo my mistake.  That would be great to find a source for the writer/director inspiration.  Although they may not admit inspiration came from a philosopher.  Personally, I think the best Disney quotes/songs come from Disney rather than philosophy.  Quotes from the Emperor in Mulan, Grandma Willow in Pocahontas and Rafiki in the Lion King are my favorites.